# kotlin calling a mutating function in class delegation

Tags: interface, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin,I don't know how to explain this but this example should be enough

```
interface Walker{
    var position:Pair<Int,Int>

    fun walk(to:Pair<Int,Int>){
        position = to;
    }

    fun trip()
}

class People(override var position: Pair<Int, Int>):Walker{
    override fun trip() {
        Log.v("TP","Ouch!!")
    }
}



class Superman(override var position: Pair<Int, Int>): Walker by People(position){

}
```

when I call

```
val sm = Superman(Pair(0,0))
        sm.walk(Pair(2,2))
        Log.v("TP","${sm.position}" //It give (0,0) instead of (2,2)
```

is there a possible way of fixing this while still using delegate

Comment: I think this doesn't work because the position being change is on the class "People" but not from the class "Superman"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
class Superman(override var position: Pair<Int, Int>): Walker by People(position)
```

to

```
class Superman(position: Pair<Int, Int>): Walker by People(position)
```

This way you only pass the initial value of `position` to the delegate instead of once more overriding `position`, which replaces the implementation that was originally delegated to `Person`.